# SQLite file not being added to the Bundle Resources

Tags: iphone, xcode, bundle

I have a file `event_setup.sqlite` which is placed in my app and copied into the `Copy Bundle Resources` section within Build Phases.

When it comes to copy this file from the Resources to the Documents Directory my app says the file cannot be found. I am using the following code to copy the file from the Resources and to tell me that the file does not exist:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    [self checkAndCreateDatabase: @"event_setup.sqlite"];
    return YES;
}

-(void)checkAndCreateDatabase:(NSString *)name{
    /*----Get the path to the Database----*/
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];

    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

    if(success){
        NSLog(@"Database already exists");
        return;
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Database does not exist");
        NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];

        bool test = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePathFromApp];
        if(test){
            NSLog(@"file does exist in resources: %@", databasePathFromApp);
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"file does not exist in resources: %@", databasePathFromApp);
        }

        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];
    }
}
```

When I run this code I get the following on the Log:

```
file does not exist in resources: /Users/samrowley/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/583D4293-3AD5-45FB-B502-9919F51FDB7B/Test.app/event_setup.sqlite
```

I have tried Cleaning the app, restarting Xcode, deleting and recopying the file into Xcode and nothing seems to work.

**EDIT:**

Output from the terminal command:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 samrowley  staff    2797 11 Feb 10:51 divider.png
-rw-r--r--   1 samrowley  staff    2803 11 Feb 10:51 divider@2x.png
drwxr-xr-x   3 samrowley  staff     102 11 Feb 10:51 en.lproj
-rw-r--r--   1 samrowley  staff    2937 11 Feb 10:51 header.png
-rw-r--r--   1 samrowley  staff    3205 11 Feb 10:51 header@2x.png
```

Comment: Post the output from this `Terminal.app` command: `ls -lR /Users/samrowley/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/583D4293-3AD5-45FB-B502-9919F51FDB7B/Test.app`.

Comment: Added the Output the the question. It's strange because I have another database in the app which is accessed the exact same way but that one works.

Comment: OK then, lets try again with some quotes: `ls -lR '/Users/samrowley/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/583D4293-3AD5-45FB-B502-9919F51FDB7B/Test.app'`

Comment: The file is not included in the Output of that command. Added part of the Output to the edit.

Comment: OK, then Watson, what do we conclude from this?

Comment: That it's not being copied into the Bundle properly.

Comment: Right.  Show us some screenshots/build scripts if you want help with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this question is that the file was not properly added to the target. To add it to the Target you need to go into File Inspector, under Target Inspector the app name must be checked for that file.

Comment: I suspect the answer to another of your recent questions is the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772517/nsinvalidargumentexception-when-using-uiimagetint-h-from-mgimageutilities

Comment: I'd imagine so. I have found a workaround for that issue now though. Thanks for your time and help by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Glad I found your answer @SamRowley because it was vexing me for a while. In every other app I've created, the sqlite database appeared in the Application Bundle without a problem, so I must've somehow added it differently this time. I included this picture of Xcode 7.3.1 because the name appears to have changed slightly. You need to have `Target Membership` checked as shown in this picture or the file won't be copied to the Application Bundle.

[image]